# ulimit for root keeps resetting

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, ulimit

Using CentOS 6.6

In `/etc/security/limits.conf` I have set the following:

```
* soft nofile 65535
* hard nofile 65535
root soft nofile 65535
root hard nofile 65535
```

In `etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf` I have set this:

```
*          soft    nproc     65535
root       soft    nproc     unlimited
*          soft    nofile    65535
root       soft    nofile    65535
*          hard    nofile    65535
root       hard    nofile    65535
```

Yet for some reason when I log out and log in to SSH as root (passwordless login using ssh key):

```
[root@server ~]# ulimit -Hn
4096
[root@server ~]# ulimit -Sn
1024
```

How do I make ulimit persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because I was using `UsePAM no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

For some reason, every tutorial online recommends disabling PAM in order to disable password logins without a key. After doing some research, it seems this is terrible advice and I'm not sure why it is recommended by so many tutorials.

With PAM disabled, `pam_limits` module is never run causing the limits to never be read from the `limits.conf` file.

Comment: Red Hat even left a comment in `sshd_config` advising _not_ to set `UsePam no`. I can't understand why so many tutorials on the Internet are so bad.